# Find max distinct in Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, unique, distinct

I have a database that records the `uniqueID, location (country code), IPaddress` and `date of visitors`. I need to craft an sql statement that builds a ***list (and counts) of the maximum number of uniqueID visits for each IPaddress on each unique date.*** Can any of you supply some samples, hints?

Thanks, Gary

Comment: In general, you want the MySQL [Aggregate Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). I can't tell from the question whether you need `MAX` OR `COUNT` or maybe both. If you post your table structure, a few sample records, and expected results you'll probably get an answer very quickly.

Comment: It's hard to give a sample without a schema.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a simple aggregation:

```
select IpAddress, date, count(*)
from t
group by IpAddress, date;
```

If you want to count distinct visitors and put them in a list, you need a visitor id.  Perhaps that is what `uniqueId` is.  If so:

```
select IpAddress, date, count(distinct UniqueId),
       group_concat(distinct UniqueId)
from t
group by IpAddress, date;
```

Comment: It is not a simple aggregation we want .. This was our test script ...  
SELECT uniqueID, MAX(Date) AS LatestAccess, 
COUNT(DISTINCT Location) AS DifferentCountries, 
COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress) AS DistinctIPCount, 
COUNT(DISTINCT Date, IPAddress) AS DistinctDate 
FROM History 
WHERE (uniqueID<>30002) 
GROUP BY uniqueID
ORDER BY DistinctDate DESC

Answer (score 1):

`Select uniqueId  , ipAddress , uniqueDate  , count (*) as visitsTotal
From utable
Group by uniqueId,ipAddress  , uniqueDate`

The Group By clause ensures uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select ip, dateVisited, count(*) group by ip, dateVisited
```